# "conquer by flood and by field"

Tags: meaning, expressions, idiom-meaning, poetry

While reading an English poem from Robert M. M'Cheyne (1813–1843), [*Jehovah Tsidkenu*](http://www.mcheyne.info/jehovah-tsidekenu/) (= Jehovah our Righteousness) there is one stanza that reads

> Jehovah Tsidkenu! my treasure and boast,
> Jehovah Tsidkenu! I ne’er can be lost;
> In thee I shall **conquer by flood and by field,**
> My cable, my anchor, my breast-plate and shield!

I'm particularly interested to know the meaning of "conquer by flood and by field". I know what each word means on its own, yet this sounds like there's more to it than meets the eye.

Comment: More text would be useful.

Comment: Text: http://www.mcheyne.info/jehovah-tsidekenu/

Comment: After M'Cheyne was converted to Christianity, he is able, through Jehovah, to conquer by divine miracle (Jehovah starting a flood) and through human conquest (on the battlefield).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several prior uses of the phrase "by flood and by field" and "by flood and field".  It means by water and by land.

For example, [The Enigmatical entertainer and mathematical associate for the year 1829, No. II](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Enigmatical_entertainer_and_mathemat/AXQPAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22by%20flood%20and%20by%20field%22&pg=PA55&printsec=frontcover) at page 56 says:

> While he will his “ voyages and travels ” recount , “ By flood and by field " what he's had to surmount

The OED has 2 poetic definitions of the word "flood":

> A body of flowing water; a river, stream, usually, a large river

and

> In wider sense: Water as opposed to land, **often contrasted with field** and fire